# MySQL how do you make a prepare statement with a variable?

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement

**This is the stored procedure I'm trying to use**

```
DELIMITER ##
CREATE PROCEDURE exportFile()
BEGIN

DECLARE filename VARCHAR(255);

SET filename = CONCAT('~/Sample',NOW(),'.csv'));
SET @outfilestmt = concat('SELECT * INTO OUTFILE ',"'", filename,"'",' FROM Results') ;

PREPARE stmt FROM @outfilestmt;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END ##
DELIMITER ;
```

**This is the error I get**

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ');
SET @outfilestmt = concat('SELECT * INTO OUTFILE ',"'", filename,"'",' FROM R' at line 6
```

**Desired Result:**

```
call exportFile
--~/Sample2012-03-14-10:42:51.cvs

call exportFile
--~/Sample2012-03-14-10:42:52.cvs

call exportFile
--~/Sample2012-03-14-10:42:53.cvs
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A semicolon is missing after

```
SET filename = CONCAT('~/Sample',NOW(),'.csv'))
```

and one brace is too much (also noted by Devart. Thanks). Change it to

```
SET filename = CONCAT('~/Sample',NOW(),'.csv');
```

Tested it to be sure. Works!

Comment: AT tombom I added the colon and updated the error message above

Comment: Do not forget to remove last bracket - ')'

Comment: Wanted to add that right now. Thanks Devart. @Gah_Jamn-it See my edited answer